# How to create a table with counts of category combinations?

Tags: categories

I have two main 'groups' of categories. I would like to have a table on a certain page that contains counts for the number of posts with combinations of categories from these two groups. So for instance, if my first groups contains categories 'A', 'B', 'C' and my second group contains categories 'X', 'Y', 'Z', I'd like to have a table like

```
   |     X     |     Y     |     Z     |
 A | count(AX) | count(AY) | count(AZ) |
 B | count(BX) | count(BY) | count(BZ) |
 C | count(CX) | count(CY) | count(CZ) |
```

with count(AX) meaning the number of posts that have both category A and category X.

How would I best go about this?

Comment: is your question about getting the counts or about creating a table? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to get the counts, I think I can manage the table. I can get the count for a single category by using "get_term_by('name', 'A', 'category') -> count;", but I can't see how I can expand this for combinations of categories.

Comment: I just managed to find a post that answered my question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254340/count-number-of-posts-which-exist-in-2-taxonomies.